# VB.net MySQL How to put two tables in a listview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listview

I want to have two tables in a list view. I have item and pawn table.

Item table has type(column) and
Pawn table has total_amount(column)

I want both of the column to appear in a single listview

```
 con.Open()

    With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "SELECT pawn.total_amount, item.type FROM pawn INNER JOIN item ON pawn.pawn_id = item.pawn_id"

    End With
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    While dr.Read
        With ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , dr("pawn_id"))
            .SubItems(1) = dr(UCase("type"))
            .SubItems(2) = dr(UCase("total_amount"))


        End With

    End While


    con.Close()
```

Comment: you might want to add the appropriate tag such as webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this one:

```
 Dim i as Integer = ListView1.Items.Count
 With ListView
 .items.Add(dr("pawn_id"))
 .items(i).subitems.add(dr("type"))
 .items(i).subitems.add(dr("total_amount"))
 End With
```